# Read a CSV file and connec to database based on columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, split

I have a `file.csv` that contains columns `databasename` and `tablename`. Using Python I have to perform an action in such a way if `column1` is pointing to a database `a` then connect to server `a` and perform action on that table. Otherwise, connect to server `b` and perform action on tables in server `b`.

Example `file.csv`:

```
database, tablename

db1, tbl1
db2, tbl2
db2, tbl3
db1, tbl4
```

Expected output: when `db1`, connect server `a` and delete from `tbl1`. When `db2`, connect server `b` and delete from `tbl2`.

I tried using pandas and `csv.reader` but unable to perform loop when the `CSV` is read as a data frame.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "log_tables.csv")
print("The dataframe is:")
print(df)
specific_columns = df[["table_name"]]
```

Or using below code:

```py
with open('log_tables.csv') as f:
    firstColumn = [line.split(',')[0] for line in f]
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the values in column1 of csv match the ones in the db table column1? or is the csv file a list of columns and action?

Comment: Check the value in column1(db) and accordingly delete records from respective tables in those database @Mudassir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example using `psycopg2` as the Python driver to a Postgres
database:

```
cat file.csv                                                                                                                                                              
database,tablename
db1,tbl1
db2,tbl2 
db2,tbl3
db1,tbl4
```

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
import csv

with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in r:
        print(row['database'], row['tablename'])
        con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=row['database'], host="localhost", user="postgres")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql.SQL("delete * from {}").format(sql.Identifier(row["tablename"])))
```

If this was a large file you would probably want to look at sorting by database to reduce the connections and/or use a connection pooler.

**UPDATE**

To read connection information from file:

```
cat pg.json                                                                                                                                                               

{"DBMSType": "POSTGRESQL", "serverName": "server_name", "databaseName": "mars", "port": "5601", "userID": "test", "password": "test_pswd"}

with open('pg.json', 'r') as pg_file:
    db_dict = json.loads(pg_file.read())

db_dict
{'DBMSType': 'POSTGRESQL',
 'serverName': 'server_name',
 'databaseName': 'mars',
 'port': '5601',
 'userID': 'test',
 'password': 'test_pswd'}

with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in r:
        print(row['database'], row['tablename'])
        if row['database'] == db_dict['databaseName']:
            con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_dict['databaseName'], host=db_dict['serverName'], user=db_dict['userID'], port=db_dict['port'], password=db_dict['password'])
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(sql.SQL("delete * from  {}").format(sql.Identifier(row["tablename"]
```

Comment: You will need to add the contents of the JSON files to your question.

Comment: the contents of the json file looks like @Adrian Klaver

{
    "DBMSType": "POSTGRESQL",
    "serverName": "server_name",
    "databaseName": "mars",
    "port": "5601",
    "userID": "test",
    "password": "test_pswd"
}

Comment: Per previous request add this to question not as a comment.

Comment: See **UPDATE** to answer.

Comment: The code is not connecting the database when tried. It's reading records but json connection is not working

Comment: Unless you add to your question the code and JSON file information you are using and the errors you are getting there is not much I say.