# Read a csv that has a db name and tablename details and connect a json that has connection details of dbname mentioned in csv file

Tags: json, postgresql, csv, psycopg2, dbconnection

I have a json connection file with sample content as below:

```
{ "DBMSType": "POSTGRESQL", "serverName": "server_name", "databaseName": "mars", "port": "5601", "userID": "test", "password": "test_pswd" }
```

and I have a csv file that has sample contents like:

```
cat file.csv                                                                                                                                                              
database,tablename
db1,tbl1
db2,tbl2 
db2,tbl3
db1,tbl4
```

now I have to read the csv to know the database and based on the database connect to respective json file where there is json file for each db
sample:

```
db1.json
{ "DBMSType": "POSTGRESQL", "serverName": "server_name", "databaseName": "star", "port": "5601", "userID": "test", "password": "test_pswd" }

db2.json
{ "DBMSType": "sybase", "serverName": "server_name", "databaseName": "trex", "port": "5601", "userID": "test", "password": "test_pswd" }


import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
import csv

with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in r:
        print(row['database'], row['tablename'])
        con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=row['database'], host="localhost", user="postgres")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql.SQL("delete * from {}").format(sql.Identifier(row["tablename"])))
```

This code is working but unable to pass json as parameter to the string

```
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=row['database'], host="localhost", user="postgres")
```

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, Added the json details to question. Please let me know if I am missing something

Comment: This needs to be an addition to your original question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609706/read-a-csv-file-and-connec-to-database-based-on-columns), where I explained how to read the JSON file.

Comment: psycopg2 is for connecting to PostgreSQL. Does it say somewhere you can connect to Sybase with it?